# PHP MySQL multiple search query using option / select HTML form tags

Tags: php, mysql, html

I'm trying to set up a basic MySQL LIKE search using two search fields.  I wan't to have it so it's multiple optional search fields e.g. `if(isset($_POST['city']) || isset($_POST['name']))` I'm not sure how to do it with a HTML`<select name=""><option value="">...`  seeing as you can't define a name for each `<select>` field.  So, first... How do you make a MySQL `<select>`search where each  yields it's own result?  Then, how would I properly query multiple search options?  Below I'm using a "text box" + `<select>` search.

```
            <input type="text" name="type" />  
            <select name="location">
               <option value="Chicago">Chicago</option>
               <option value="New York">New York</option>
            </select>
            <input type="submit" value="Search" />
```

MySQL:

```
              $query = "SELECT 
              name, type, description, location, zip_code, phone_number
              FROM search
              WHERE type LIKE '%$type%'
              OR location LIKE 'Chicago'
              OR location LIKE 'New York'
              ";
```

I know I'm doing something wrong on the OR clauses.  I"m not totally sure how to properly do the `<option> / <select>` HTML form tag search query.

Comment: What are you trying to do? Are you trying to populate your <select> with values from MySQL, or are you trying to look up MySQL-rows based on values from a multiple <select>?

Comment: MySQL-rows based on values from a multiple <select>.  Just a search based on multiple select.

Answer (score 4):

HTML

```
<select multiple name="location[]" size="2">
```

PHP

```
$w     = array();
$where = '';
foreach ($_POST['location'] as $loc){
  $loc = mysql_real_escape_string($loc);
  $w[] = "location = '$loc'";
}
if (!empty($_POST['type'])){
  $w[] = "type LIKE '%".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['type'])."%'";
}
if ($w) $where = implode(' OR ',$w);
```

Comment: Does this make the result based on the <option>?  Is the <option> value returned in the from of an array() from $wh[]?  Do <option> values typically get returned this way?  Thanks for the answer.

Comment: 1. just look at HTML part carefully. 2. var_dump() every variable in this code to see it's contents. 3. think

Comment: why are you using like search location is hardcoded city names and your version can select some unwanted results

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you want but try this:

PHP:

```
// mysql escape
$locations = array_map("mysql_real_escape_string", $_POST['location']);
// add locations to query string
$locations = implode("','",$location);

$query = "SELECT 
              name, type, description, location, zip_code, phone_number
              FROM search
              WHERE location IN ('$locations')
              ";
if (isset($_POST['type']) && !empty($_POST['type'])){
  $query .= " or type LIKE '%".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['type'])."%'";
}
```