# php MySQL LIKE search

Tags: php, mysql, html

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [PHP MySQL multiple search query using option / select HTML form tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7315885/php-mysql-multiple-search-query-using-option-select-html-form-tags)

I'm trying to make a basic search based on a drop down select option.  I want to return a result based on the option selected.  However, it doesn't seem to be working.

```
    <?php
mysql_connect('localhost','root','');\
mysql_select_db('location');
?>

<center>
<form action="" method="post">
<select name="place">
    <option value="one">one</option>
    <option value="two">two</option>
    <option value="three">three</option>
</select>
<input type="submit" value="search" />
</form>
</center>

<?php
if(isset($_POST['place'])) {
    $place = $_POST['place'];
    if(!empty($place)) {
        $query = "SELECT
                    description
                    FROM location
                    WHERE place LIKE '%$place%'
                    ";
        if($query_run = mysql_query($query)) {

        if($result = mysql_fetch_assoc($query_run)) {
            $description = $result['description'];



                echo $description;
            }
        }
    }
}

?>
```

**UPDATE:**  never mind got it.

Comment: This is not how `mysql_query()` works. Refer to the [manual](http://php.net/mysql_query) for examples. Also turn on error reporting - there will be error messages in the code you show

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enable error reporting to see what mistake you made. Then use:

```
$result= mysql_fetch_array($query_run);
echo $result['description'];
```

And, which could be said for about every php + mysql question: read about SQL Injection.